# Why is my heater always flowing some water under the floor?

Tags: plumbing, boiler, heater

Looking for some answers about why is there a constant audible hissing and flow in the pipes coming to my heater at home. This is electric model.

The pipe that hisses goes along the boiler and down under the floor. Looks like in the drain there is always some water movement too. It is marked with red circle. When I grab it, it quiets down significantly, otherwise sounds like spraying water inside under high pressure.

The pipe coming in to that valve is going from main water line via pressure regulator.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: turn off the recirculating pump to test the noise

Comment: I don’t think I have one as it takes a while for hot water to get to taps when opening in the morning. Also, grabbing the circled pipe quiets it down as well as I can feel the water flowing in it.

Comment: The red box is a pump, or should be if it's working correctly.

Comment: Red box is hooked up to cold water pipes that are supplying both cold and hot water and before the cold water shit off for the house(not the sprinkler though). Can’t be the pump IMHO.